# Discord.js | Random Images Embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'd like to know how to put random images in embeds:

This is my code:

```js
case 'aes':
  number = 100;
  imageNumber = Math.floor (Math.random() * (number - 1 + 1)) + 1;
  message.channel.send( {files: ["./images/" + imageNumber + ".jpg"] } )
  break;
```

How would I make it post the images in an embed???

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation ? There is a code example for creating an embed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```js
case 'aes':
let maxImageNumber = 100;
let imageNumber = Math.floor (Math.random() * (maxImageNumber - 1 + 1)) + 1;
let imageName = `${imageNumber}.jpg`
let imagePath = `./images/${imageName}`

let file = new Discord.MessageAttachment(imagePath);
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
    embed.setImage(`attachment://${imageName}`)
message.channel.send({ files: [file], embed: embed });
break;
```